# How can humans evolve a single burning hand?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, humanoid

The environment is a temperate enclosed valley on earth (or is like Earth) that has caused the humans trapped in it to evolve different. Their size is normal. They gave evolved a gel that oozes on the left hand and a little down the wrist that they can lite (the skin in this section looks darker than rest of the body). They can keep the hand on fire for up 7 minutes before having to stop to prevent overheating their hand. They have 40 minutes' worth of gel before their bodies have to produce more. All but the thumb on the right hand can develop claws (thinking it is a genetic chance of between 2-4 claws but never one or none). They have gone more carnivorous route, able to eat even bone. Their intelligence is the same as humans but haven't moved past the stone age. Does this evolutionary result seem plausible? And what other changes to the body would have to happen to make this work (I know the mouth would likely have to, but I am not sure of how much it would change the appearance of the head.)

Comment: You are not telling anything about what drove the evolution in the direction you describe. How can we tell if it makes sense or not?

Comment: "_Their intelligence is the same as humans but haven't moved past the stone age_" that's suspect in itself, even without the weird fuel-pump-left-hand which is going to be nigh-on impossible to explain. But you do need to share some more details.

Comment: i doubt if "having your hand engulfed in fire for 7 minutes" is even possible without "having ridiculously hard and thick skin, making it unusable as hand". also: what would be  the evolutionary benefit? we regular humans can make fire with our hands _without_ torching them. and we already could during the stone age. we can also eat the only nutritional part of the bone (the marrow), and we could do so long before we could make fire.

Comment: It would be *MASSIVELY* easier to have them exude some chemical and collect it for use on more conventional torches or simple lamps.

Comment: You should edit the question to make it match the title, if that's what you want.  Alas, the close voters are circling.

Answer (score 3):

**Ritual Scarification.**

The most believable explanation is that the black flaming hand is an artificial creation. It comes from the ritualistic removal of claws and scarification or burning of the left forearm. This self-mutilation causes the skin to leak a fatty combustible substance
that can be set on fire.

Note I am unaware of such a substance in reality. Whale oil can be used to power lanterns but probably requires a purification process and then to be made into a mist before it will take a flame. You cannot simply strike a match and set a whale on fire. You can of course add olive oil or animal fat to an existing fire, and the fire will heat and aerosolize the fat for you.

The arm-oil substance is easier to ignite than conventional means, and allows the species to start fires easier, despite being less smart than humans.

Some problems with natural evolution:

**It's hard to chomp through bones and be smart.**

One reason humans are (a) smarter and (b) have a weaker jaw than early apes is the lack of a skull ridge:

[image]

That mowhawk-looking doodad at the top of the skull -- that's there for a reason. The ridge serves to anchor large jaw muscles and allow a stronger bite. But it also steals headspace from a larger cranial capacity. So it's hard to have both at once.

There is also no need to bite through bones once you get to the tool-using level of smartness. Just smash the bones with a rock and suck out the marrow.

**Fire-hand McGuggins.**

The fire-hand adaptation is hard to believe for the following reasons:

(1) There are no mammals with this degree of asymmetry. There are some mammals with asymmetric teeth, but the only ones with asymmetric arms are crabs and lobsters:

[image]

(2) No animal excretes flammable substances. At least on purpose. The most common flammable substance is animal fat. However this stuff is hoarded as an energy source so it's not obvious why it would be secreted.

(3) Seven minutes sounds like a long time to burn over such a large surface area. There do exist whale oil lanterns that can burn for hours.

[image]

But they are designed to have a small aperture to conserve fuel.

(4) It is metabolically expensive to produce fuel. The fuel must be energy dense enough to burn, and you are sacrificing using those calories inside you body. The calories gained from producing flame -- for example to light a fire to cook food -- would have to be more than those gained from using the fat as an energy store.

Comment: If your jaw is strong enough to bite through a living bone, then it's also strong enough to break itself when biting a bone...unless the jaw is made of steel, it's gonna break

Comment: Same reason why people can't break a skull with  a punch, the same punch would break their own hand bones.

Comment: Bombardier beetles excrete substances which are not flammable but chemically heat to high temperatures.

Comment: @RPGlife Not all bones are the same strength.

Comment: @RPGlife hyenas, jaguars and crocodiles can all crunch bones with little effort. With the proper structure and adaptations, it's anything but far fetched that they could too.

Comment: `No animal excretes flammable substances` - [Objection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_dung_fuel)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If we are allowed processing then the statement is false. But the substance (poo) as excreted is not flammable is it? There is processing to dry out the poo and make poo cakes to burn in your poo cake fireplace.

Answer (score 1):

## Pretty implausible.

I'll be honest: I don't this is something that could ever appear through normal natural selection. It could certainly appear as a bioengineered species, but that's about it.

firstly: they're asymmetric, and wildly so. While things like asymmetric limbs can be found in arthropods, especially crabs, it's not something wildly prevalent in vertebrates outside of how your organs are placed. Even through no creature is truly symmetric, vertebrates with mostly symmetric limbs tend to be the norm and not the exception. That said: your creature would need some extreme pressures just to break the asymmetry in such a way. They'd need pressures simultaneously acting on having claws on the right hand, having no claws on the left hand anfd producing this gel on their left hand only.

Secondly: the design is too intelligent. Sure the ability to produce flammable oil might sound cool, but when you look at it in more depth, it's borderline impossible from a practical standpoint. Whales for example can produce oil, which is flammable, but said oil usually never leaves the whale. Assuming your creature is producing a gel that's similar in composition and chemical formula, not only is it extremely expensive to produce and problematic to store, it would have no practical purpose on an evolutionary standpoint. Remember that traits don't pop up out of nowhere, there is an entire process just for w final trait to appear, and if we look at your creature, the ONLY purpose of said gel is apparently to catch on fire. Your creature needs a lot of storage space (because 40 minutes worth of a fuel that's most likely no denser than water and is seemingly not spent with "care" in terms of quantity ) and specialized systems just to... Constantly ooze a metabolically expensive chemical that happens to be flammable.

If your species never figured out how to make fire this would have remained as useless to their survival as it normally is when not being used, and even with such an ability, your group would still be destroyed by a similar species that instead used their brains to make use of other flammable components in the environment in order to weaponize fire, with the added bonus that they don't need a crazy amount of adaptations just to keep said fire burning for 7 minutes before they need to put it out, because they'll likely be lighting up spears and won't need to waste a lot of energy fabricating a chemical just for it to be wasted.

And then the claws: its not implausible for a humanoid to have them. The ancestors of apes had claws, but adapted said claws into nails given their lifestyle. It's honestly harder to explain your creature going from claws to nails back to claws and in only one hand, **and with seemingly pointless variation in number of claws**. A single clawed hand means you'll have poorer ability to, say, cling onto a large prey animal or climb a tree trunk than if you had 2 clawed hands. In this case the asymmetry part is harder to explain than the actual claws, because you said it yourself that they went down a more carnivorous path, which would nicely explain both keeping claws on every digit of both hands and a stronger jaw with a dentition more adapted to a carnivorous lifestyle. It's also hard to explain why they can or can't develop claws depending on the individual. If they are useful, invividuals with no or few claws would be removed from the gene pool. If they're detrimental, individuals with claws would be removed. For such a difference in number claws would basically need to be irrelevant an non-costly to maintain, which begs the point: why would they have claws if said claws aren't useful enough to be selected into being? Females like them? Something else?

The skull isn't terrible to explain, and we have examples of mammals capable of crushing bones wit their Jaws, like [hyenas and their ancestors](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/prehistoric-hyenas-teeth-show-bone-crushing-carnivore-roamed-canadian-arctic-180972436/). It's honestly the easiest part of the whole creature.

Basically it seems more like a gimmicky humanoid bioengineered by an advanced species for fun than something that could practically evolve as a functional creature. The only possible explanation I could give for such wild traits other than "they were planned a traits nd these things were bioengieered" would be "the species have sexual preferences that makes the world of arthropod mating seem tame"

As for potential ways to make it more plausible:

1- symmetry. Just choose: claws or no claws. Random claws that pop up between 2 or 4 fingers aren't normally a trait that just happens and sticks around. The structural differences between a clawed finger and one with a nail is pretty different. Decide if they do or don't use claws and give them said claws. At most have the thumbs have smaller claws, but claws nonetheless.

2- ditch the gel. It's metabolically expensive, impractical, slows down your creature, is worthless as a weapon without something to light it on fire and requires a lot of pressures and adaptations just to work without actively harming the creature itself, which means it's more likely to be wiped out by natural selection than not. If you really want something that can be weaponized and gives a burning sensation, just give them specialized poison glands that can be squished by muscles, spraying said poison onto whomever it's aimed at. Many natural poisons and venom can cause a burning sensation, especially if it hits sensitive places like the eyes, with things like cobra venom being capable of causing blindness. Boom, you have your chemical that causes a burning sensation, and a creature from another intelligent species can easily be tricked into thinking they can spray something that makes you burn like if on fire, and while still metabolically expensive, it not nearly as problematic as the ability to ooze an equally expensive gel that is useless without something to light it on fire.

3-Jaws. They're alright. You'll need to watch for how they're structured, and your human might have a skull more similar in structure to a gorilla's with teeth more like those of a hyena. Do note though that bigger brains and a strong bite usually don't go along well (the greatest mammalian bite ever belongs to the Thylacoleo, whose small brain created an ideal skull shape for anchoring its powerful msucles).

These changes add in another bonus: they don't need to have discovered fire just to make one of their natural abilities more than a waste of energy and resources, and a predatory lifestyle means they can't really settle down and move past the stone age with the same ease we did until they learn to domesticate their food a and don't need to go around hunting as often.

Answer (score 0):

-There are and have been plenty of human carnivorous species/tribes/ethnicities, and pretty much all humans can digest bone or have a traditional dish of bones.

-Flames can be as cold as 400 °C or around 800 °F .
Just keeping your hand half a meter away from such a flame will start hurting, I know cause I have a chimney in my home, chimneys just so happen to have an average temperature of 800 °F .
Even you if your hand doesn't burn or hurt you, your blood will still overheat, which can easily kill you. Those creatures will need some strong system for losing heat faster than their blood can boil.

Very low bodyfat and exposed veins as well as large ears or sails are common methods animals use to make their blood cooler. Also the most obvious ones of being tall and thin like Africans.

-everything else is a plausible.

Also as suggested by Daron, fat is very flammable, so flammable it is used in explosives and it runs car engines.

Producing fat costs 9 kilocalories per gram +15% to 30% depending on the individual metabolic efficiency, it's different for every person.

Answer (score 0):

## They never *learned* to start fires.

Primitive humans in areas like the Okavango Delta (well, OK, I'm not sure if there *are* any like that) had seasonal access to wildfires.  The fires would leave behind cooked meat and they would gorge themselves.

Your humans did not become intelligent, but developed a secretion they could use to transfer fires from place to place.  Likely the system is not *inherently* asymmetrical, but when they favor one hand for doing it, the secretion from that hand increases, while the other dries up over time.

A biological firestarter is unprecedented, but this is *biology*.  Of course evolution can come up with something.  No other species has ever gone that way because only humans can use fire rather than suffer from it.  There's no precedent for it, but we can suppose piezoelectric crystalline deposits are involved.